# How to upload an excel file to google collab and plot the data with a linear regression in python

Tags: python, excel, google-colaboratory, linear-regression

I'm just trying to plot the data in `Google Collab` and then use a linear regression to interpret the data. So far I am able to upload the file, but I cant get the data to display, and then I want to run a linear regression on the file.

```
import io
import pandas as pd
from google.colab import files

uploaded = files.upload()

xlsx_file = io.BytesIO(uploaded.get('Infant Mortality Rates.xlsx'))
df_first_sheet = pd.read_excel(xlsx_file, 'Infant Mortality Rates.xlsx')
```

So far I have this, but as I said I cant get the data to display or be read in `collab`

Answer (score 1):

I think the last line is incorrect. You should put the sheet name there instead of the file name. Something like this:

```
df_first_sheet = pd.read_excel(xlsx_file, 'Sheet1')
```

Change `Sheet1` to the name you are using for your sheet.

Then you can run below in a new cell to display the data and confirm the file loaded correctly:

`df_first_sheet`

Comment: ok thanks.  Ill try that and let you know if that works.

Comment: Just started learning how to code so apologies for a very basic question.

Comment: Glad I could help. Can you please give my answer an upvote? I've been here awhile but this is my first answer.